# Hyperledger peer start node

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm using hyperledger v1.0 after i used make peer and running peer node start it shows this error

```
2017-05-09 09:12:14.407 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 042 Failed connecting to orderer:7050 , error: grpc: timed out when dialing
```

I added orderer 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts but it does not fix my problem.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Are you using docker ? If so, you should expose the port 7050 with the option "-p" when you start the orderer.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not under any firewalls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you all for your response, i resolved my issue by usind `

### docker pull fabric-orderer

` and then run it